# Azure Function - Resize image stored in a blob container

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, imageresizer, azure-webjobssdk, azure-functions

I've answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874081/azure-c-sharp-webjob-using-imageresizer-not-properly-setting-content-type/) related to Azure Webjob and Resizing a image stored as a blob and so I am trying to do the same using a `Function App`

Each time a new blob is uploaded, I send a a new queue message.
My function is triggered by the queue message and bind to the uploaded blob. I also have a second input binding that binds to another CloudBlobContainer to be able to upload new resized images to another blob container.

My function looks like that:

```
#r "System.Web"
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using ImageResizer;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

private static readonly int[] Sizes = { 800, 500, 250 };

public static void Run(string filename, Stream blobStream, CloudBlobContainer container, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Verbose($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {filename}");
    // Extract the filename  and the file extension
    var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
    var ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

    // Get the mime type to set the content type
    var mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename);

    foreach (var width in Sizes)
    {
        // Set the position of the input stream to the beginning.
        blobStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Get the output stream
        var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        ResizeImage(blobStream, outputStream, width);

        // Get the blob reference
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{name}-w{width}.{ext}");

        // Set the position of the output stream to the beginning.
        outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        blob.UploadFromStream(outputStream);

        // Update the content type =>  don't know if required
        blob.Properties.ContentType = mimeType;
        blob.SetProperties();
    }               
}

private static void ResizeImage(Stream input, Stream output, int width)
{
    var instructions = new Instructions
    {
        Width = width,
        Mode = FitMode.Carve,
        Scale = ScaleMode.Both
    };
    var imageJob = new ImageJob(input, output, instructions);

    // Do not dispose the source object
    imageJob.DisposeSourceObject = false;
    imageJob.Build();
}
```

The associated `function.json` file:

```
{
"bindings": [
  {
    "queueName": "newfileuploaded",
    "connection": "crazytunastorageaccount_STORAGE",
    "name": "filename",
    "type": "queueTrigger",
    "direction": "in"
  },
  {
    "path": "input-images/{queueTrigger}",
    "connection": "crazytunastorageaccount_STORAGE",
    "name": "blobStream",
    "type": "blob",
    "direction": "in"
  },
  {
    "name": "container",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "output-images",
    "connection": "crazytunastorageaccount_STORAGE",
    "direction": "in"
  }
],
"disabled": false
}
```

And the `project.json` file:

```
{
"frameworks": {
  "net46":{
    "dependencies": {
      "ImageResizer": "4.0.5",
      "WindowsAzure.Storage": "4.3.0"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Now when I compiled the function, I always got this error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.ResizeBlobImage'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind Blob to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer'.

Is this type supported for the moment ?

Comment: You should probably use an Output for the function under Integrations in settings for Azure Function instead of creating the blob yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `CloudBlobContainer` is supported. I tried a quick sample myself now, and the below function works for me, using the same binding metadata you showed above. I'm also using the same version of the WebJobs SDK in `project.json`.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

public static void Run(
    string blobTrigger, Stream inputBlob, Stream outputBlob,
    CloudBlobContainer container, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"Container name: {container.Name}");

    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function processed {blobTrigger}");
    inputBlob.CopyTo(outputBlob);        
}
```

Not sure why this wasn't working for you. I have seen some Portal glitches from time to time (bugs we're fixing) that sometimes cause issues.

Comment: I've retried and it works... I've had to force a recompilation. Thanks