# Azure Function - Resize image stored in blob storage for all containers not a specific one

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953126/azure-function-resize-image-stored-in-a-blob-container) to resize images stored in my blob storage.

My problem is that my website creates a new container for every bill it is handeling and add pictures to that specific "bill" container.

Is there a way to trigger my azure function for every container in a storage and not to specify a concrete one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Roman mentioned Event Grid covers this scenario, we recently put up a tutorial on doing this exact scenario based off that existing sample using queues.. It can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-upload-process-images

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported at the moment, you can track the status of this request in [Add ability to create blob triggers on a container names that match a pattern](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/779)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any workaround? using HttpTriggers for example?

Comment: You could send a queue message every time you add a blob, and then bind the container name to a field in that message

Answer (score 1):

Also, I do recommend to look at the **Blob Storage Event Grid** (now in the preview), see more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview).