# Resizing images in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, image-processing, azure-blob-storage

What are some good methods to resize images hosted in Azure Blob Storage?

---

I can think of two basic approaches:

#### 1. After upload

When the image is uploaded, generate the resized versions, you need.

#### 2. On demand/intercept

Intercept requests for resized images and process them on the fly - potentially cache the result, so you don't have to resize every time.

---

I find method two to be the most elegant, because you do not have to know ahead of time, which sizes you need - or set up some kind of background resizing process.

I find that the methods used by ImageResizing.net are pretty awesome, and have used them in the past, but their recent license changes makes it an nonviable option for many kinds of project, where 250-8000USD on just image resizing is not in the budget.

Are there any alternatives to ImageResizing.Net in the option 2 category - or any other projects in the first category, that are worth checking out, so you don't have to start from scratch?

Comment: When/where/how you resize an image is completely up to you and your app's workflow. Regardless, you'll need to do your processing on local / attached storage, vs directly in a blob (since blobs do not deal with file I/O like files, aside from File Storage service). Licensing costs are irrelevant here. Tool recommendation questions (such as asking for alternatives to a product/library) are off-topic.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Can you suggest a way for me to find out, if a great replacement for Imageresizing.net exists?

Comment: Have a look at this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/a/36877764/4167200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to follow Thomas’s reply in this thread to see whether it could be able to achieve your requirement. I searched the web and found an alternative approach called [Simple.ImageResizer](https://github.com/terjetyl/Simple.ImageResizer) which could be used to replace the ImageResizing.NET. With a package called "Simple.ImageResizer.MvcExtensions", you could add a dynamic image resizing into your ASP.NET MVC Site. I tested it on my side and found it works well, please try to refer to the link above and find out whether it could meet your requirement.