# create thumbnail request and queue it in azure queue storage finally web job should pickup and create it using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-webjobs, azure-queues

Can any one of you suggest me how to proceed with below 2 points as i am confused. I have an asp.net mvc application that will upload image and other address details to blob storage.

Now i need to ad below logic to it. 
I  am confused about the flow
Azure queue storage-> create image thumbnail--> web job .

Any articles or code snippets  will be helpful.

1    Requests for creating thumbnails for each uploaded photo will be queued to 'Azure Queue storage'. This should be done as soon as a photo is uploaded by user for a contact.
2  Web-Job should be picking up requests to create thumbnail from the uploaded photos.

Comment: you can have a look at these two answers [Azure Function - Resize image stored in a blob container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953126/azure-function-resize-image-stored-in-a-blob-container) and [Azure WebJobs Blob Trigger - multiple resizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869097/azure-webjobs-blob-trigger-multiple-resizes/)

Comment: Thank you @Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused about the flow Azure queue storage-> create image thumbnail--> web job.

According to your description, I suggest you could try below flow.

Firstly, you could upload the image from local to the blob storage in your MVC application and store the blob url to the SQL database.

After uploading completely, the code will write a message to an Azure queue.

In web job the WebJobs SDK polls the queue for new messages by using queue trigger.

When a new message appears, the WebJob creates a thumbnail for that image and store the image to the blob. At last it will store the thumbnail url to the sql database.

More details, I suggest you could try to read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started).

It contains the same logic and code snippet.